# scale transition not working in firefox

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I've got this transition working smoothly in chrome and safari but it is not working in firefox. In firefox it does not zoom in, but it shows the enlarged image instantly. Maybe somebody knows what's wrong...

I've made a jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/WYfZz/

```
ul.polaroids_portfolio li a:hover { -webkit-transform: scale(1.75); -moz-transform: scale(1.75); 
-ms-transform: scale(1.75);-o-transform: scale(1.75);transform: scale(1.75);
 position: relative; z-index: 5; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no `-moz-transition: -moz-transform .15s linear;` on `ul.polaroids_portfolio a`, you just have the `-webkit-` version.

See http://jsfiddle.net/WYfZz/5/

Also, you shouldn't forget to also put the unprefized version for transitions at the end as well (both transitions and transforms will be unprefixed in Firefox 16/ Opera 12.5/ IE 10). Same goes for `box-shadow` (you'd be better off using the unprefixed version instead of the prefixed ones; I can understand using the `-webkit` prefix to support Android or Blackberry, but Firefox supports the unprefixed `box-shadow` since FF4)